# Is there a way / Perl Module to Control CRON on remote hosts

Tags: perl, cron

The idea is to have a central controller, that can manage cron, for many hosts. I have looked at [Schedule::Cron](http://search.cpan.org/~roland/Schedule-Cron-1.01/lib/Schedule/Cron.pm) and [Config::Crontab](http://search.cpan.org/~scottw/Config-Crontab-1.33/Crontab.pm)

But none of them provide the remote capability. There is one that looks promising, IPC::PerlSSH, but not sure if i understand how to run Config::Crontab using [IPC::PerlSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/IPC-PerlSSH-0.16/lib/IPC/PerlSSH.pm)

If anyone has some experience in this area please let me know. Perl does claim to be good for Linux admin tasks and this seems like one of the top tasks to be scripted. But doing it JUST on the local machine, after ssh'ng into it does not sound like fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# untested!
use Net::OpenSSH;
use Config::Crontab;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, ...);
$ssh->system({stdout_file => 'crontab.out'}, 'crontab -l');
my $cc = Config::Crontab->new;
$cc->read('crontab.out');

# manipulate $cc crontab here:
# ...

$cc->write('crontab.out.1');
$ssh->system({stdin_file => 'crontab.out.1'}, 'crontab -');
```

Comment: When i run your suggested code against my host , i get 
no crontab for kahmed
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Config/Crontab.pm line 74.

Answer (score 0):

`IPC::PerlSSH` simply uses SSH to execute Perl code remotely.  The catch is that all remote nodes must also have the `Schedule::Cron` or `Config::Crontab` modules installed for this to work.

It would be preferable to use a SCP library (e.g. `Net::SCP` or `Net::SCP::Expect`) to simply bring over the crontab of interest from the remote node, massage it locally using the `Cron` library of your choice, then upload the massaged crontab back to the remote node.  With this approach there is no need for the remote nodes to even have Perl installed.